# ElasticSearch sort by value

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch 5 and I would like to do sorting based on field value. Imagine having document with category e.g. genre which could have values like sci-fi, drama, comedy and while doing search I would like to order values so that first comes comedies then sci-fi and drama at last. Then of course I will order within groups by other criteria. Could somebody point me to how do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Elasticsearch Sort Using Manual Ordering**

This is possible in `elasticsearch` where you can assign order based on particular values of a field.

I've implemented what you are looking for using [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) which makes use of [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html) script. You can refer to the links I've mentioned to know more on these for below query would suffice what you are looking for.

Also assuming you have `genre` and `movie` as keyword with the below mapping.

```
PUT sampleindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "genre": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":  "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "movie": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":  "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can make use of below query to get what you are looking for

```
GET sampleindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [{
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "if(params.scores.containsKey(doc['genre.raw'].value)) { return params.scores[doc['genre.raw'].value];} return 100000;",
                "params": {
                    "scores": {
                        "comedy": 0,
                        "sci-fi": 1,
                        "drama": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    { "movie.raw": { "order": "asc"}
    }]
}
```

Note that I've included sort for both `genre` and `movie`. Basically sort would happen on `genre` and post that further it would sort based on `movie` for each genre.

Hope it helps.

Comment: that's not quite what i wanted. I want to define order of the genres by supplying it. no asc,desc but rather define first genre 1, then genre 2, then genre 3 and also being able to say that within genre 1 i want then order by some property asc|desc

Comment: Hey @aRagornol, please check the answer once again. I've updated it and I think it would suffice what you are looking for.

Comment: For me, above query was throwing illegal_argument_exception; With below change in "inline" script I was able to run the query:
          "inline": "if(params.scores.containsKey(params._source.listingStatus)) { return params.scores[params._source.listingStatus];} return 100000;",