# Deciding custom order when sorting by enums in Elasticsearch using Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a Nest class which contains a `Condition` enum property.

```
class Item {
    public Condition Condition { get; set; }
}
```

The condition enum looks as follows:

```
public enum Condition
{
    New = 0,
    Used = 1,
    Broken = 2,
    BrandNew = 3
}
```

Now here's the problem. When I search and sort by the condition, it is ordered as `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, but I would like to decide a custom order (`[3, 0, 1, 2]`).

Is this possible entirely on the Elasticsearch side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order object by enum in custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630925/order-object-by-enum-in-custom-order)

Comment: Perhaps this link can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791530/3838328 Basically I've used script to define my manual ordering and sorted it using ES querying.